# If an integer $n$ is chosen at random from $1$ to $96$ inclusive ,what is the probability that $n(n+1)(n+2)$ is divisible by 8?

Tags: probability

In this one If I consider that n is even then probability that the number $n(n+1)(n+2)$ will be divisible by 8 will be 1/2 ,Now if n is odd then for n(n+1)(n+2) to be divisible by 8 ,n+1 should be a multiple of 8 ,Now how to find the probability among 96 numbers such that it is a multiple of 8 ?

Comment: Please use Latex format for writing equations and also provide your thoughts about the problem.

Comment: Well..we can certainly use the fact that the product of three consecutive integers $(n)(n+1)(n+2)$ is always divisible by $6$....

Comment: If n is even, it is always divisible by 8, because either n or n+2 will be divisible by 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the total numbers are $96$. for an odd number to be multiple of 8 using expression $n(n+1)(n+2)$ the number $n$ should be a number preceding to a multiple of $8$ starting from $8$ itself so first number is $7$ and such is an AP whose last term is $95$. So total terms which are $1$ less than a multiple of $8$ ie odd are $12$ thus the probability is $\frac{12}{96}=\frac{1}{8}$. Numbers with $4m-2=\frac{1}{4}$ and then $4m=\frac{1}{4}$ so addition is $\frac{5}{8}$

Comment: This answer is wrong, as there are $60$ such values of $n$ (not $12$).

Comment: Can you tell how 60

Comment: I have edited it.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the equation $$n(n+1)(n+2)\equiv 0\pmod{8},$$ we see that this happens when $$n\equiv 0,2,4,6,7,8\pmod{8},$$ and so we get a probability of $\frac{5}{8}.$

Comment: It's worth noting that in order for this to be accurate, the number of elements in the range must be a multiple of $8$.

Comment: I couldn't get your explanation sir , can you please explain it once more

Comment: How did you get n=4 ?

Comment: @RadhaGogia: When $n\equiv 4\pmod{8}$, then $4|n$ and $2|n+2$, so the polynomial is divisible by $8$. The same reasoning applies whenever $n$ is divisible by $2$ - one of $n,n+2$ will be divisible by $4$, and the other one will be divisible by $2$. The final case of $n\equiv7\pmod{8}$ comes from consider when $n+1$ is divisible by $8$.

Answer (score 1):

1. $n=8m$
2. $n=8m-1$
3. $n=8m-2$.
4. $n=4m$
5. $n=4m-2$

1) is a subset of 4) so we can remove 1).

3) is a subset of 5) so we can remove 3).

So,

2. $n=8m-1$ $\rightarrow P=\frac18$
3. $n=4m$ $\rightarrow P=\frac14$
4. $n=4m-2$ $\rightarrow P=\frac14$

$$\frac18+\frac14+\frac14=\frac58$$

Comment: Maybe you have'nt take in consideration that the numbers are  between  $1$  and  $96$ .

Comment: I did take it in consideration.

Comment: But maybe this does not affect the answer, as between $1$ and  $96$  the numbers are equaly  partitioned  conguruent to  $8$.

Comment: That's what all the answerers here were taking into account already.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

- $n\equiv0\pmod8 \implies n\cdot(n+1)\cdot(n+2)\equiv0\cdot(0+1)\cdot(0+2)\equiv\color\green0\pmod8$
- $n\equiv1\pmod8 \implies n\cdot(n+1)\cdot(n+2)\equiv1\cdot(1+1)\cdot(1+2)\equiv\color\red  6\pmod8$
- $n\equiv2\pmod8 \implies n\cdot(n+1)\cdot(n+2)\equiv2\cdot(2+1)\cdot(2+2)\equiv\color\green0\pmod8$
- $n\equiv3\pmod8 \implies n\cdot(n+1)\cdot(n+2)\equiv3\cdot(3+1)\cdot(3+2)\equiv\color\red  4\pmod8$
- $n\equiv4\pmod8 \implies n\cdot(n+1)\cdot(n+2)\equiv4\cdot(4+1)\cdot(4+2)\equiv\color\green0\pmod8$
- $n\equiv5\pmod8 \implies n\cdot(n+1)\cdot(n+2)\equiv5\cdot(5+1)\cdot(5+2)\equiv\color\red  2\pmod8$
- $n\equiv6\pmod8 \implies n\cdot(n+1)\cdot(n+2)\equiv6\cdot(6+1)\cdot(6+2)\equiv\color\green0\pmod8$
- $n\equiv7\pmod8 \implies n\cdot(n+1)\cdot(n+2)\equiv7\cdot(7+1)\cdot(7+2)\equiv\color\green0\pmod8$

Note that the number of elements in the range $[1,96]$ is a multiple of $8$.

Answer (score 0):

All 48 even values of $n$ in the range qualify, as values of $(n+1)$ from $8\times 1$ thru $8\times 12$,

thus there are $60$ favorable cases,
and $ Pr = \dfrac{60}{96} = \dfrac{5}{8}$

Comment: Might as well leave it as $\frac{60}{96}$ (or rewrite it as $\frac58$).

Comment: Of course ! :-)